# Is it possible to create a 3D model off a 2D PNG image (advanced shapes) using WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, model, 3d, 2d

I am searching for a way to convert some advanced 2d shapes given in PNG format to 3D models, basically "extruding" the image to certain dimension given lets say in millimeters. Search a bit trying to maybe find a solution using meshes but it doesn't seem that I am getting closer. *NOT* asking for a complete solution, a direction to start heading to would be really nice though, cause i am a bit stack and do not know where/how to start.

Sample image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHcwB.jpg

Comment: you need to try and separate your bitmap into sections that you can use to create shapes and use them to build your 3D object
possible steps:
Reduce image so it only shows, for example, all red Pixels -->
Use some math magic to calculate vectors going around the extracted pixels-->
create a shape based on these vectors --> extrude them in 3D

Comment: check out this link as an interesting source http://www.aforgenet.com/articles/shape_checker/ or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29782124/how-to-extract-front-shape-in-an-image-in-c-sharp

Comment: if you hope to have a real foto of for example a traffic scene and have the software automatically detect a traffic light and turn it into a 3D object don't even consider going on with your idea

Comment: I would think it could be done though you cannot just throw an image at code and have it do that with everything in the world.  You'd need a front-end analysis piece that asks : is it a flower?  Is it an animal?  Is it amphibious?  That way you have a "general" model of what areas move "out" and for how far.  So a stem of a rose is only 1-2 mm while the rose itself can be many mm.

Comment: Thank you all very much for your help! @DenisSchaf Nothing like that, its just some non rectangular shapes without any background. For example, some connected lines draw in illustrator exported without the background.

Comment: Also Added an image in case it helps to understand what shapes i will be working with.

Comment: Seeing your image now I recommend using emguCV to extract the lines and calculate them into a vector from there try finding your way tho paths/shapes and go on with your research. emguCV is a wrapper for OpenCV. check out this link to get started https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29156091/opencv-edge-border-detection-based-on-color

Comment: also if you only want to draw lines and get them in 3D it might make more sense to start with a vector file instead of a bitmap